# Como seleccionar una fila de jtable que guardé en un documento.txt

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

A esta tabla cuando presiono el boton mostrar clientes me abre el documento.txt y me lo muestra en la tabla, pero cuando selecciono una fila de la tabla y le doy seleccionar me sale el error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0`,

[image: Frame tabla_cliente]

Yo quiero que al seleccionar una fila y luego al botón `SELECCIONAR` me muestro los datos en estos jtextfield.

[image: JTextfield]

Código de botón Seleccionar:

```
 private void btn_seleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // Seleccionar del Jtable a los txtfield
    if (tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() >= 0) {
        try {
            //tabla cliente = n 
            String nombreCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 0));
            int dni1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 1)));
            String direccionCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 2));
            String correoCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 3));
            int telefono1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow(), 4)));

            txt_cliente.setText(nombreCliente);
            txt_dni.setText(String.valueOf(dni1));
            txt_direccion.setText(direccionCliente);
            txt_correo.setText(correoCliente);
            txt_telefono.setText(String.valueOf(telefono1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error terrible en: "+e);
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe seleccionar un producto.");
    }
```

}

Este es el código para mostrar el documento.txt en la tabla_cliente.

```
public DefaultTableModel listapersonas(){
    
    
    Vector cabeceras = new Vector();
    
    cabeceras.add("Nombre");
    cabeceras.add("Dni");
    cabeceras.add("Direccion");
    cabeceras.add("Correo");
    cabeceras.add("Telefono");
       
    DefaultTableModel modelobjCliente1 = new DefaultTableModel(cabeceras,0);

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("DatosClientes.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String d;
        while ((d=br.readLine()) != null) {                
            StringTokenizer dato = new StringTokenizer(d,"|");
            Vector x = new Vector();
            while (dato.hasMoreElements()) {
                x.addElement(dato.nextToken());
                
            }
            modelobjCliente1.addRow(x);
            
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en aca: "+e );
    }
    return modelobjCliente1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar ponerlo así:

```
String nombreCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() -1 , 0));
int dni1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() -1 , 1)));
String direccionCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() -1 , 2));
String correoCliente = String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() -1 , 3));
int telefono1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mdlcliente.getValueAt(tabla_cliente.getSelectedRow() -1 , 4)));
```